# belongs_to relationship does not work until I save -- am I 'doin it wrong'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Probably this is just the way Rails works, but I want to double-check because I am new to it and I'm not sure if I am missing something.

I am creating a fairly complicated set of model that has a number of nested has_many/belongs_to relationships.  Initially, I tried just using the create() method, but since that initiates a database connection every single time it ended up taking a lot longer than it ought to.  So instead I use new() to create all of the objects, use << to add the nested models to higher models, and then at the very end I do a save() on the top-level model.

This all works, but I noticed that the belongs_to relationship does not work until I do the save.  In other words:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bars
end
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :foo
end
f = Foo.new
b = Bar.new
f.bars << b
puts "It's nil!" if b.foo == nil   #yup, it's nil
f.save
puts "It's good!" if b.foo != nil  #yup, it's good
```

It makes sense I guess; I mean, it can't set up the id field to point to its Foo until that Foo actually *has* an id, and that won't happen until I save.  It's not a big deal, I only noticed it because the way I had initially written the (rather complicated) initialization, one of the lower-level models was calling up to get some information from its grandparent, and that wasn't working.  The code's cleaner now that I took that out anyway, but I can't help this nagging feeling that I'm doing it totally the wrong way, and there should never be a situation where the has_many relationship is temporarily broken until I actually save to the database.

Anyone want to set my mind at ease and/or tell my the "right" way of doing it?

Comment: cant you just use f.bars.new ?

Comment: I believe f.bars.new would have the same issue.  In the actual code, I am calling a separate function to construct the Bar, so it makes more sense to use << than collection.new.  I agree in this toy example, it is silly to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just answered your own question with this line:

> It makes sense I guess; I mean, it can't set up the id field to point to its Foo until that Foo actually has an id, and that won't happen until I save

Since `belongs_to` works off of a foreign key on Bar matching up to the id on Foo, you can't have a relationship until that ID exists.

As a side note, you can do

```
f.bars.new
```

To set up the relationship automatically without having to do `f.bars << b`

Comment: Good, thanks, just wanted to make sure I wasn't using a bad practice or something.

I have a separate function that is building the Bar (has to parse some XML), hence using << instead of collection.new

Comment: Glad to help!  If this answers your question, please take a moment to hit the checkmark next to my answer to close out the question

Answer (score 1):

This is correct; until there's an ID in the `Foo`, there's none for the `Bar` to use to get its `Foo`.